# Kjots compile issue in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kde, plasma

I'm trying to install Kjots from source. The source package is available at http://download.kde.org/stable/kjots/5.0.1/src/kjots-5.0.1.tar.xz

Followed the install instructions from https://community.kde.org/PIM/KJots. However, getting the below error.

```
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/kdelocalprefix/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ECM" (requested
  version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

      ECMConfig.cmake
      ecm-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ECM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ECM_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ECM" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/usr/local/src/kjots-5.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Anyone has anyidea on fixing the above error ?

Answer (score 3):

The `ECMConfig.cmake` file is provided in Xenial by the `extra-cmake-modules` package, so you need to install that - either from your favorite package manager or via the command line

```
sudo apt install extra-cmake-modules
```

For errors related to the following message

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5KCMUtils"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5KCMUtilsConfig.cmake
    kf5kcmutils-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5KCMUtils" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5KCMUtils_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5KCMUtils" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

install `libkf5kcmutils-dev` package.

```
sudo apt install libkf5kcmutils-dev
```

You may also need these packages

`libkf5kio-dev`, `libkf5parts-dev`, `libkf5akonadi-dev`, `libkf5mime-dev`, `libkf5akonadinotes-dev`, `libkf5pimtextedit-dev`, `libkf5kontactinterface-dev`, `libgrantlee5-dev` packages.

Comment: installed and now another error.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5KCMUtils"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5KCMUtilsConfig.cmake
    kf5kcmutils-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "KF5KCMUtils" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5KCMUtils_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5KCMUtils" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.

Comment: `KF5KCMUtilsConfig.cmake` should be provided by package `libkf5kcmutils-dev`

Comment: thanks, installed it. now another error.
CMake Error at src/noteshared/CMakeLists.txt:14 , (kcfg_generate_dbus_interface):
  Unknown CMake command "kcfg_generate_dbus_interface".

Comment: @VipinMs How did you fix the last `kcfg_generate_dbus_interface` error message?